# How to enter validation for a choice of a question in Google forms using script editor?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want that when someone tries to fill the checkbox, the checkbox automatically unchecks itself according to the time of the day.

Here is my code:
`

```
function myFunction() {
  var myForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var title = myForm.getId();
  var choicesArray = [];
  var item = myForm.getItemById('xxxxxxxx').asCheckboxItem(); // xxxxxx is whatever the id is 
  var choices = item.getChoices();
  var d = new Date();
  choices.forEach(function(a) {
      if (a.checked == true && a.getValue() == "First")
          if (d.getHours() >= 17)
          a.checked = false;
      if (a.checked == true && a.getValue() == "Second")
          if (d.getHours() < 17)
          a.checked = false;
  });
}
```

`
After creating trigger nothing happens and i am able to select both the checkboxes which shouldn't happen. Nor the trigger triggers.

if that is not possible then how to delete the second choice and only show the other one?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that I cannot still understand your actual question. I think that this is due to my very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand your actual question. when I could correctly understand your actual question, I would like to think of a solution. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I think that my answer was not useful for your actual question. I think that I have to study English more.

Comment: ok i got it running thanks. the problem was onOpen function fires trigger runs only for users who have edit permissions not for users who don't have. So it was only triggering for me not for other people hence it always showed a fixed date and time from last triggering event. I bypassed it by running the trigger every minute so it changes the date and time every minute hence works for people who don't have edit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have put semicolons right after `if`. This terminates the if.

Remove the semicolons & put the statements right after `if` instead of the next line.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var title = myForm.getId();
  var choicesArray = [];
  var item = myForm.getItemById('xxxxxxxx').asCheckboxItem(); // xxxxxx is whatever the id is 
  var choices = item.getChoices();
  var d = new Date();
  choices.forEach(function(a) {
      if (a.checked == true && a.getValue() == "First")
          if (d.getHours() >= 17); // <--- remove ;
          a.checked = false;
      if (a.checked == true && a.getValue() == "Second")
          if (d.getHours() < 17); // <--- remove ;
          a.checked = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me but still it doesn't  do anything after removing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function myFunction() {
    var myForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var title = myForm.getId();
    var choicesArray = [];
    var item = myForm.getItemById('xxxxxxxx').asCheckboxItem(); // xxxxxx is whatever the id is 
    var d = new Date();
    item.setChoices([item.createChoice(d.getHours() > 11 ? "first" : "second")]);  
  });
}
```

then run set the trigger to run every minute or else if set onOpen it will run    only who have edit permissions not for all the people.

Thanks @Tanaike for help !!!